# I wanted to know that under what circumstances is the sharing button enabled on the detail view for a record?

Tags: security, sharing, record, owd, manual-sharing

Now, I have a custom object for which I have the OWD set as private, then I am able to see the sharing button on the detail page of the record, but even if I set it to public read/write, I can still see the sharing button. Maybe in the new update for lighting they have enabled the manual sharing button which doesn't take into account of your OWD settings. In addition to that I feel the only way to enable or disable that sharing button is through the page layout.

A. A developer has added a button on the page layout

B. When record sharing is enabled in t e user profile

C. When record sharing is set to public read only or private for the object

D. When record sharing is set to public read/write for the object

These are the 4 options to my above question.

I am highly confused here, I feel the answer should be A.

Comment: The share button is would be visible when the OWD is not set to Public Read/write and the button is made available by adding it to the relevant page layout. It is highly unlikely that the button would be visible with OWD set as Public Read/write. Can you clarify what you are referring to by "new update for lighting" in your question?

Comment: I was referring to the manual sharing button they have added on the record page in the dropdown. Earlier it was only available in salesforce classic.
Now my issue was that this 'sharing' option in the dropdown is always visible irrespective of the OWD settings, and when I say this I check it when i login as some other user who doesn't have admin access.